# Using dropwizard-migrations: Could not find implementation of liquibase.logging.Logger

Tags: liquibase, dropwizard

I'm getting a pretty odd exception that I can't figure out the cause of. When I run a `db status`, I get:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not find implementation of liquibase.logging.Logger
        at liquibase.logging.LogFactory.getLogger(LogFactory.java:19)
        at liquibase.logging.LogFactory.getLogger(LogFactory.java:30)
        at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(DatabaseFactory.java:67)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.<init>(Liquibase.java:52)
        at com.yammer.dropwizard.migrations.ManagedLiquibase.<init>(ManagedLiquibase.java:47)
        at com.yammer.dropwizard.migrations.AbstractLiquibaseCommand.run(AbstractLiquibaseCommand.java:39)
        at com.yammer.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:58)
        at com.yammer.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:53)
        at com.yammer.dropwizard.Service.run(Service.java:61)
        at com.derp.SomeService.main(SomeService.java:27)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not find implementation of liquibase.logging.Logger
        at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.newInstance(ServiceLocator.java:179)
        at liquibase.logging.LogFactory.getLogger(LogFactory.java:17)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not find implementation of liquibase.logging.Logger
        at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.findClass(ServiceLocator.java:145)
        at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.newInstance(ServiceLocator.java:177)
        ... 16 more
```

I'm not sure how to resolve it. Googling a bit, it seems to be a somewhat intermittent problem that has, in the past, yielded bugfixes in Liquibase. I didn't expect this to happen in such an integrated feature. I am using dropwizard-core/hibernate/migrations 0.6.2. I'm using the com.smokejumperit.gradle.OneJarPlugin gradle plug-in to package it all up, which I think is also responsible for class loading.

Anyway, I'm at a bit of a loss. Any ideas? Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Sorry, haven't seen this before. What version of liquibase are you using? Does it work when you run this on the command line?

Comment: Liquibase is retrieved through the dropwizard-migrations dependency. [Here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.yammer.dropwizard/dropwizard-migrations/0.6.2) are its dependencies, but for convenience, it's liquibase-core 2.0.5.

Comment: Maybe it helps to look at the [source](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/2_0_x/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/servicelocator/ServiceLocator.java) and try to find out what could be the cause of this. Sorry I am not using dropwizard, so I can only give you this hint.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I'll have to debug through Liquibase. New experience, I suppose! I'm hoping there's just some dependency I'm missing, but if it were that easy, I probably would've found it already (plus why would dropwizard-migrations not have such a dependency already?).

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  Seeing same thing.

Comment: Nope, never did unfortunately. I haven't tried newer versions of dropwizard, though.

Comment: I'm getting this with Dropwizard Migrations as well. Version 0.8.0

Comment: Had the same issue today. It couldn't get implementation of Logger because my war file name contained {, } symbols, so path was incorrect. Changed the war file name, no exception.

Comment: Liquibase-core 2.0.5 seems really old: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/releases/  Does this still occur in the latest stable release?